# Widget Toolkits for Python 3

Tags: gtk, widget, python-3.x

Because I like to future-proof my programs as much as I possibly can, I use the latest technologies under development. However, GTK (along with many other widget toolkits) does not appear to be compatible with Python 3. Are there any widget toolkits that fully support Python 3?

Thanks.

Comment: This is so dumb. Is python 3 just less popular? Still?

This sounds like a case where you have to use either a deprecated binding or unsupported version of a language.
Or use QT, a toolkit developed in 15 years ago before pokemon was released.

Comment: I guess you can temporarily use python 2.6 then easily switch when PyObject releases a new version for python 3.x. Any idea when that will happen? The last release seems to be April 2011. http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygobject/2.28/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, there are two main ways of doing GTK+ programming with Python:

- [The deprecated PyGTK](http://www.johnstowers.co.nz/blog/index.php/2011/04/03/end-of-an-era-pygtk/), which use static GTK+ bindings, and therefore tedious to maintain. It often lagged behind GTK+ state-of-the-art as a result.
- [The more modern PyGObject](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject), which is moving towards dynamic bindings by using [gobject-introspection](https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection).

Of these, only the second method works with Python 3. This work is fairly new, and you are likely going to face some bugs here and there, and perhaps changing API, not to mention not-enough documentation. If you proceed anyways, go join [the mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/python-hackers-list) and/or the IRC channel, `#python @irc.gimp.net`, but do start with [the tutorial](https://github.com/sebp/PyGObject-Tutorial).

Comment: not to mention not-enough documentation, it is not really an issue with the bindings made dynamics using introspection since, then the documentation made for C development of Gtk will work just the same.