# Is there a way to directly send a python output to clipboard?

Tags: python, linux, clipboard

For example, if a python script will spit out a string giving the path of a newly written file that I'm going to edit immediately after running the script, it would be very nice to have it directly sent to the system clipboard rather than `STDOUT`.

Comment: The solution would be OS dependent, is that alright?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ I assume it would be, but I'm working entirely inside Linux, so I would like a solution for Linux.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use an external program, [`xsel`](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['xsel','-pi'], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input='Hello, World')
```

With `xsel`, you can set the clipboard you want to work on.

- `-p` works with the `PRIMARY` selection. That's the middle click one.
- `-s` works with the `SECONDARY` selection. I don't know if this is used anymore.
- `-b` works with the `CLIPBOARD` selection. That's your `Ctrl + V` one.

Read more about X's clipboards [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/200444/why-do-we-have-3-types-of-x-selections-in-linux).

A quick and dirty function I created to handle this:

```
def paste(str, p=True, c=True):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    if p:
        p = Popen(['xsel', '-pi'], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(input=str)
    if c:
        p = Popen(['xsel', '-bi'], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(input=str)

paste('Hello', False)    # pastes to CLIPBOARD only
paste('Hello', c=False)  # pastes to PRIMARY only
paste('Hello')           # pastes to both
```

---

You can also try pyGTK's [`clipboard`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkclipboard.html) :

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()

clipboard.set_text('Hello, World')
clipboard.store()
```

This works with the `Ctrl + V` selection for me.

Comment: I tested this snippet but it seems it doesn't work for my settings. After doing `python abovescript.py`, then I middle-clicked my mouse in the terminal, but no `Hello, World` shows up.

Comment: @nye17 Which method are you trying? Does it give you any errors?

Comment: The first `clipboard` one, doesn't work but no errors reported at all.

Comment: There are two different clipboards in most Linux systems - the middle click and the `ctrl+c`/`ctrl+v` clipboards. check the other one - the middle click clipboard is managed at a lower level then GTK IIRC.

Comment: The second `xsel` doesn't work either. Could it be because of my window manager? I'm using terminator under Xmoand in Debian.

Comment: @tobyodavies I was aware of that, but Ctl-V doesn't work either, for both methods. Puzzling...

Comment: I'd expect the GTK method not to work with terminator just cause I'm pretty sure that captures `ctrl+v` (there may well be a "paste" option in an edit menu though)

Comment: You need the `-i` flag for xsel... try the new version - works for me

Comment: @nye17 adding `-i` (or `-pi`) to xsel made it work for the middle click clipboard. The GTK one works with the `Ctrl+V` clipboard for me (on Ubuntu)

Comment: @tobyodavies ok, I tried all three, "middle-click", ctl-v, and the terminator-menu "paste". For the `clipboard` module, all three failed; for the `xsel -i` one, only the `middle-click` works.

Comment: @nye17 that's expected - the `xsel -i` is only supposed to write to the middle-click clipboard, and the GTK version will only ever write to the `ctrl+c`/`ctrl+v` clipboard (which should be accessible through right-click/paste)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ @tobyodavies Thanks guys! Now the terminator-menu `paste` works with `-b` and "middle-click" works with "-p".

Comment: @nye17 I am glad you figured it out. It surprises me that terminator's `paste` works with `-b` though.

Comment: How about mentioning [PyGObject](https://github.com/sebp/PyGObject-Tutorial/blob/master/examples/clipboard_example.py) rather than PyGTK. [I've heard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130381/60075) that PyGTK is deprecated and PyGObject is the replacement.

Comment: I had the same problem with the GTK solution: in a script, it doesn't work, but on the Python console it does. I thought it had something to do with the program quitting too quickly after clipboard.store(), and I think I was right: if, in a script, after clipboard.store() you use raw_input() to get the user to hit a key before the program ends, then it works. It is kind of a hack, but for my purposes it was fine.

Answer (score 17):

As it was posted in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11063483/212112), if you want to solve that within python, you can use [Pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip) which has the added benefit of being cross-platform.

```
>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
>>> pyperclip.paste()
'The text to be copied to the clipboard.'
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not really a Python question but a shell question. You already can send the output of a Python script (or any command) to the clipboard instead of standard out, by piping the output of the Python script into the `xclip` command.

```
myscript.py | xclip
```

If `xclip` is not already installed on your system (it isn't by default), this is how you get it:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

If you wanted to do it directly from your Python script I guess you could shell out and run the xclip command using `os.system()` which is simple but deprecated. There are a number of ways to do this (see the `subprocess` module for the current official way).  The command you'd want to execute is something like:

```
echo -n /path/goes/here | xclip
```

Bonus: Under Mac OS X, you can do the same thing by piping into `pbcopy`.

Comment: I prefer if the string specified by the script be sent to the clipboard, rather than all the output being piped to `xclip`, as the final output and the desired string are not necessarily the same. But you are right, I can use `subprocess` to send it to `xclip`, although I would prefer a slightly less "brute-force" way.

Comment: doing it in python is nicer - allows the code to have more output than just a filename...

Comment: Add a command-line flag to suppress everything but the pathname, then, or to optionally send it to standard error (so you can pipe it to `xclip` without catching the rest). You need a command-line flag anyway since you don't want to clobber the user's clipboard without being explicitly told to, so why not make it more unixy?

Comment: @kindall This time I wanna go for more pythonic ;-)

Comment: A good reason not to use xclip:  you don't control the shell environment necessarily.   None of the cloud servers that I work on provide xsel or xclip, so a pure-python solution is much preferred.

Comment: How is this a shell question? `xclip` and `xsel` are certainly not shell built-ins, and they are implemented somewhere, somehow. It's a legitimate question to wonder how to implement their functionality in Python.

Comment: Well, one could always take a look at how the different GUI libraries for Python implemented clipboards, and write a compiled .so file for Python that does the same thing in any context.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out this is not "Python and batteries" as it involves GUI operations. So It is platform dependent. If you are on windows you can use win32 Python Module and Access win32 clipboard operations.
My suggestion though would be picking up one GUI toolkit (PyQT/PySide for QT, PyGTK for GTK+ or wxPython for wxWidgets). Then use the clipboard operations. If you don’t need the heavy weight things of toolkits then make your wrapper which will use win32 package on windows and whatever is available on other platform and switch accordingly!

For wxPython here are some helpful links:

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Clipboard-class.html

http://wiki.wxpython.org/ClipBoard

http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25549