# Pyperclip does not persist if script exits

Tags: python, clipboard, pyperclip

I want to store something into the clipboard via a python script.

It's basically just `pyperclip.copy('text')`.
I'm using Fedora 21 with AwesomeWM. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063458/python-script-to-copy-text-to-clipboard#comment54819131_25476462) that a clipboard manager is needed to store it permanent in the clipboard. I installed `parcellite`. It now works, if I use it in an terminal, via

```
$python
$>>> import pyperclip
$>>> pyperclip.copy('teststring')
```

BUT if I do the exact same thing in an script

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('teststring')
```

and execute this script with `python filename`.

It won't get stored in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with pyperclip-1.5.27. With this script, test.py:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')

$>python ./test.py
```

Then doing Ctrl+V pastes:

```
The text to be copied to the clipboard.
```

Are you sure pyperclip.copy is running or is your script more complex than that?

Comment: As is said I use `parcellite` with AwesomeWM. It might work for you, because it might be handled automatically. It should work in my case as well, only for some reason it doesn't work if I execute it in a script.