# Read text from clipboard in Windows using ctypes

Tags: python, clipboard, ctypes, python-3.6

I'm trying to get the text stored in the clipboard by just using `ctypes` in `Python 3.6`. I tested a lot of solutions I found on Stack and GitHub, but they only work for `Python 2` to `Python 3.4`.

**This is the code you'll find almost everywhere:**

```
from ctypes import *

def get_clipboard_text():
    text = ""
    if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(c_int(0)):
        h_clip_mem = windll.user32.GetClipboardData(1)
        windll.kernel32.GlobalLock.restype = c_char_p
        text = windll.kernel32.GlobalLock(c_int(h_clip_mem))
        windll.kernel32.GlobalUnlock(c_int(h_clip_mem))
        windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
    return text
```

I tested it in `Python 3.4`. It worked fine and returned the text in the clipboard. But running the same script on `Python 3.6` always returns `None`. I could not find a solution for `Python 3.6` so far.

I'm wondering if anybody could help me out since I don't know much about `ctypes` and `C` programming at all.

Comment: Could you include the imports you used? Currently the code throws lots of `NameError`s.

Comment: I'm sorry, the imports have been added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is you are using 64-bit Python 3.6 so handles are 64-bit, and you are passing them as c_int (32-bit).

With ctypes, it is best to be explicit about all the arguments and return types.  the following code should work on 32- and 64-bit Python 2 and 3.

Also, CF_UNICODETEXT will be able to handle any text you copy.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as w

CF_UNICODETEXT = 13

u32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
k32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')

OpenClipboard = u32.OpenClipboard
OpenClipboard.argtypes = w.HWND,
OpenClipboard.restype = w.BOOL
GetClipboardData = u32.GetClipboardData
GetClipboardData.argtypes = w.UINT,
GetClipboardData.restype = w.HANDLE
GlobalLock = k32.GlobalLock
GlobalLock.argtypes = w.HGLOBAL,
GlobalLock.restype = w.LPVOID
GlobalUnlock = k32.GlobalUnlock
GlobalUnlock.argtypes = w.HGLOBAL,
GlobalUnlock.restype = w.BOOL
CloseClipboard = u32.CloseClipboard
CloseClipboard.argtypes = None
CloseClipboard.restype = w.BOOL

def get_clipboard_text():
    text = ""
    if OpenClipboard(None):
        h_clip_mem = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
        text = ctypes.wstring_at(GlobalLock(h_clip_mem))
        GlobalUnlock(h_clip_mem)
        CloseClipboard()
    return text

print(get_clipboard_text())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code works perfectly! I did not think of 32-bit and 64-bit versions of python.

Comment: @chrizator, kernel and window handles are 32-bit. But special handles for the latter that have a negative value must be sign extended to 64-bit. Also, some handles really are memory addresses such as `HMODULE` and `HGLOBAL`, as is obviously the result of `GlobalLock`. In practice, always declare `argtypes` and `restype` when working with handles and pointers to avoid hard coding implementation details and assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So by defining `argtypes` and `restypes` the code is working for 32 & 64 bit? Sorry for asking these stupid questions, but I am really new to this topic.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, would you have the same code for setting a text in clipboard with `ctypes` (maybe with `SetClipboardData`)? It would be great to add it here for future reference :) It would provide a dependency-free solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063458/python-script-to-copy-text-to-clipboard (well, only `ctypes`).

Comment: @Basj Answered on your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77647740/235698).