# Is there a way to save an image as a variable from the clipboard with ctypes (no other libraries)?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

Is there a way to read the clipboard with `ctypes`?

I'm trying to make a program which virtually presses <kbd>printscreen</kbd>, grabs the image from the clipboard, and saves it as a variable. I can't use any libraries other than `ctypes`, `pygame`, `time`, `random`, `sys`, and `os` (basically just the libraries included with python).

Can anyone help?

I’m using Windows 10 and Python 3.7 (32 bit).

Edit: The only answer to the question [Read text from clipboard in Windows using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132401/read-text-from-clipboard-in-windows-using-ctypes) doesn't work with pictures.

[Is there a way to capture an image of the screen in python with ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728754/is-there-a-way-to-capture-an-image-of-the-screen-in-python-with-ctypes) is a related question I asked.

Comment: For images it's a bit trickier, since additional processing is required. You may consider replacing *ctypes* with (external) *pywin32* which has a *Python* friendlier interface.

Comment: I can't use any external libraries because I am using a school computer. My school also blocked command prompt, so I can't use pip either.

Comment: There are some complex structures that you'll most likely need to define, so the *ctypes* approach might get generate unusually long code, that has nothing to do with the question per se (like in the other question *argtypes* and *restype* setting). Did you check whether *pywin32* isn't already installed (`import win32api`)? Or maybe *pygame* could have some functionality that could help you? Anyway, how are you supposed to run the code without a console?

Comment: @CristiFati, my school has python installed on all the computers, and pywin32 is not installed (I already tried importing it).

Comment: OK, you didn't answer to my question. Besides, this task seems more than overwhelming for a student. Nevertheless, you have all the needed material to go on.

Comment: I have no idea what the additional prossesing would be.