# Is it possible to copy numpy variable values to clipboard in PyCharm?

Tags: numpy, pycharm, clipboard

If I rightclick and select `Copy Value`

[image]

it copies corrupted excerpt only:

[image]

In 21st century wasn't it possible to just send all the numbers to clipboard?

Answer (score 11):

Say your NumPy array is `mynparray`. Then you can do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(mynparray)
df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)
```

Comment: I wanted to thank you so much for this solution. It works really awesome for me.

Comment: On Linux you must install a package for this to work; none of which worked for me. https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#not-implemented-error

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a PyCharm bug: max buffer size is 255.

Try this workaround: press `Insert` and evaluate `print(dat)`. The value will be dumped to console, where copy is working fine.

Also you can go ahead and evaluate `pyperclip.copy(str(dat))` to copy in python (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11063458/712995)).

Answer (score 2):

```
print(dat.tolist())
```

and then copy it from the run Console

Comment: or use `str(dat.tolist())` in the debugger and copy the str-value.