# Open or copy .docx without saving it

Tags: python, python-docx

I am creating some part of a document that the user can then use for his own purposes. Currently, it is saved to desktop and automatically opened, meaning that the user has to copy the content, close it and delete it. I was wondering if there was a way to either

- Directly copy the content of the document to clipboard without saving it (`like document.copy()`)
- If not possible, if I can at least open the document without having to save it so Users dont need to manually delete it.

Simply copying to clipboard as if it was a string doesn't do the job.

Edit: What I want to do would be:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
document.copy()
```

Comment: If you just want to copy some text to clipboard, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11063483/933770).

Comment: @AliMomenSani The thing is the document isn't just text.

Comment: Your document's contents have to come from docx? Would an HTML equivalent work?

Comment: @AlexReinking No, I create a document and want to get it into the clipboard