# Python - Copy LISTS to Clipboard

Tags: python

I have some Python code that produces a list like this:

```
[(('infection',), 548), (('data',), 543), (('plant',), 514), (('host',), 513), (('species',), 489)]
```

I want the code to copy this list to my clipboard in that exact format i.e, the same as if I was to print the list.

However, the packages I have found i.e. clipboard, pyperclip do NOT allow lists to be copied.

I can join the list into a string, but then I lose the brackets and commas etc (or its a faff to add them back in).

Is there a package or a nifty bit of code that can copy LISTS to the clipboard?

Many thanks

Comment: wrap the whole list in `str()` before pushing to the clipboard.

Comment: before copying to clipboard try to convert the list into string using `str(list)`

Comment: Yep, perfect. I am an idiot. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```py
import os
def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)
lst = [...] #your list
addToClipBoard(str(lst))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you Sid. The other packages worked i.e. pyperclip/clipboard, I just had to wrap the list in str(). I was making it more complicated by trying to join the list into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example for macOS based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371323/14119806)) that doesn't require additional packages.

```html
import subprocess

list_to_put_on_clipboard = [(('infection',), 548), (('data',), 543), (('plant',), 514), (('host',), 513), (('species',), 489)]
list_as_str = '\n'.join([str(item) for item in list_to_put_on_clipboard])
subprocess.run("pbcopy", universal_newlines=True, input=list_as_str)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMwTb.png) is the result when copying to excel

Notes:

- Not all types may support conversion to str
- You may want to use a different delimiter than '\n' above, but '\n' produces what I think is the desired Excel output in this case

**For other operating systems**, according to comments in the above link, instead of "pbcopy" use:

- "xclip" for **Linux**
- "clip" for **Windows**