# DEPRECATION WARNING:

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, centos

I am trying to following the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063458/python-script-to-copy-text-to-clipboard) question in an attempt to copy to clipboard however all solutions provided in the answer seem to have failed me. On macOS, I have successfully used pyperclip and subprocess.run to copy to clipboard as described in the linked post, however on centOS neither works. I have also tried using Tkinter on macOS however when I run the following simple code:

```
  from tkinter import Tk
  r = Tk()
```

I get the following deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
```

I don't really want to build my application with deprecated dependencies however seeing that centOS doesn't support pyperclip or subprocess.run I feel like I have no other options.

Specifically I would like to know if there exists a good solution to my problem, that is, I want to copy to clipboard on centOS and ideally, I want a solution that will work on "most" platforms. Please note that I am using python3. Thanks

Comment: Are you using python2-x now?

Comment: No I'm using python3 on both centos and macos. Thanks for pointing out that this wasn't clearly stated, I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: In Python3,if you want to import tkinter you need to use `import tkinter` not `import Tkinter`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have changed my question again. I just ran this and unfortunately I still get the same deprecation warning

Comment: Maybe you need to update your `tkinter`.Here is [something](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) maybe will help.

Comment: on linux `pyperclip` uses bash command `xclip` or `xsel` so if you have installed `xclip` or `xsel` then it should work or you can do the same using even `subprocess.run("xclip ....")`. But `xclip` or `xsel` may need `X11` `XWindow` (the same with `tkinter` - it needs `XWindow`/`X11`)

Comment: BTW: do you really has to use clipboard?  Maybe you could save it in file and later read from file? It works on all systems.

Comment: I would like to save a password to clipboard so the user can paste the password into a login without needing to show the password on screen. However, even beyond this particular goal, I feel that there should be a straightforward way to interface with the clipboard on linux. Thanks for recommending xclip and xsel, I'll take a look at these

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Ignore the DEPRECATION WARNING:
   See this post [Using tkinter with Catalina, how to avoid deprecation warning?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376165/using-tkinter-with-catalina-how-to-avoid-deprecation-warning) helped me a lot.
2. Upgrade Python:
   See the official documentation [IDLE and tkinter with Tcl/Tk on macOS](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolved this problem for my environment: I am on a Mac Monterey 12

1. `brew install tcl-tk`
2. `brew install python-tk@3.11`
3. `pyenv install 3.11.4` (uninstall it if you have it already, then reinstall it. This will make the python use the existing version of tk)
4. `pyenv local 3.11.4`, now run your python code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer on the original question, because it is deprecated now, but because it is linking to this question, I will post my solution here (which assumes pyenv is installed):

I followed the steps of @Karthik R here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73930554/6429967 but this didn't solve my problem. What I did and worked was based on the following article: https://blog.lanzani.nl/2020/install-tkinter-macos/ which expands @Karthik R's solution approach

**Solution** (Note: change the pyenv version to your version)

```bash
$ brew uninstall tcl-tk
$ pyenv uninstall 3.10.8
$ brew install tcl-tk
$ export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"
$ export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'"
$ 
$ pyenv install 3.10.8
$ pyenv global 3.10.8

# Test the installation
$ python -m tkinter
```

EDIT: this solution was tried out on an Intel-based iMac with macOS Ventura 13.1 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer also found here: [DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated, M1 Mac in Vs Code - global Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472167/deprecation-warning-the-system-version-of-tk-is-deprecated-m1-mac-in-vs-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

If you have Homebrew installed, you can update `tk` with:

```
brew uninstall tcl-tk --devel
brew install tcl-tk
```

Which is the recommended option

Then *you may need* to add `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"` to your `.zshrc` file:

If you are using a `zsh` terminal:

[image: Zsh tab]

Use:

```
echo "# For tkinter 
export PATH=\"/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Or if you are using a `bash` terminal:

```
echo "# For tkinter 
export PATH=\"/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

> [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
>
> [Reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268880/warning-the-version-of-tcl-tk-8-5-9-in-use-may-be-unstable)
>
> [Python's offical `tk` upgrade docs](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8)