# DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated, M1 Mac in Vs Code - global Python

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

(M1 MBA 2020, MacOS 12.3.1)
So inside of Vs Code, when I select my interpreter as `Python 3.8.9` from my `usr/local/bin Tkinter` it runs as I want it to.

[image: This is the working interpreter]

Here is the running code for reference.

[image: Running Code]

The problem arises when I am trying to use the Global `Python 3.8.9` interpreter (`usr/bin/python3`). When the code runs, the application ends up looking like this.

[image: not working tkinter]

Additionally, when I run the code the terminal reads the following:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
```

How is it possible for me to fix this error? Or update my global Tkinter version without straying away from `Python 3.8.9`. Furthermore if any more info is needed I'll be happy to provide, sorry I'm new to this stuff

Packages used in the app:
tkinter, Pillow, tkmacosx

One last thing, when I get rid of all mentions of the package Tkmacosx, the app appears like this:

[image: app without tkmacosx]

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315121

Comment: Did you install python directly from python.org ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have Homebrew installed, you can update `tk` with:

```
brew uninstall tcl-tk --devel
brew install tcl-tk
```

Which is the recommended option

Then *you may need* to add `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"` to your `.zshrc` file:

If you are using a `zsh` terminal:

[image: Zsh tab]

Use:

```
echo "# For tkinter 
export PATH=\"/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.zshrc
```

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Or if you are using a `bash` terminal:

```
echo "# For tkinter 
export PATH=\"/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

> [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
>
> [Reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268880/warning-the-version-of-tcl-tk-8-5-9-in-use-may-be-unstable)
>
> [Python's offical `tk` upgrade docs](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8)

Comment: Thanks for the response, so when I tried to uninstall Tkinter it said "--devel" is not supported... Anyways ignoring the "--devel" part I followed your instructions and the update error still appears :(

Additionally, tck-tk has been added to '/opt/homebrew/Cellar', now how can i "link" this into my global python interpreter?

Comment: Maybe add the full path of your `tck-tk` bin files to your path, as shown in the answer, but with your path obviously. It would look something like `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH` in your bash or zsh profiles. Try `$ where tcl-tk`

Comment: @darkmatter6384 no worries :) did adding your new `tcl-tk` to path fix the issue?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan thanks although I was simply pushing to a repo and my creds were borked.  Dont know why it worked as I wasnt using Code. But thanks.

Comment: tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
  `brew install python-tk@3.10`

Comment: installing python after this worked for me. I use pyenv.

Answer (score 8):

Answer from Freddy below https://stackoverflow.com/a/72472483/9842697  worked.

(this note was to be a response to the answer)

I have python 3.10.6 installed via pyenv, pyenv installed via homebrew.
(Uninstall with --devel does not work)

- installing tcl-tk with homebrew and reinstalling python 3.10.6 with pyenv, makes the python installation use the homebrew version of tcl-tk and after this IDLE works fine.

```
% brew install tcl-tk
% pyenv install 3.10.6
% python
>>> import idlelib.idle
```

Comment: Installing Python *after* tcl-tk did the trick!