# Tkinter deprecation warning

Tags: python, tkinter

DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

I tried updating Tkinter and Python on my Mac but without success. I did read some other posts with similar problems, but found none helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated, M1 Mac in Vs Code - global Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472167/deprecation-warning-the-system-version-of-tk-is-deprecated-m1-mac-in-vs-code)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A feature of a language you are trying to use being depreciated means that the developers of the language are discouraging you from using that feature because it has been superseded by a newer/better version, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9208190/12388841). It will still work as intended, but it may not be supported in a future version of Python. You can still use it, but this is something to keep in mind if you are making something that you plan on supporting in the future.

Updating Python will not make a difference to whether it works unless the version you are updating to does not support tkinter anymore, in which case, you would not be able to use it.