# Copy text to clipboard using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I would want to copy a text to the clipboard using batch script so I don't have to open a text file to select all text and copy. I tried this code:

```
echo | set /p= hello & echo.world |clip
```

Output

```
world
```

Expected clip (desired)

```
hello
world
```

but it only clipped:

```
world
```

What are options so I can copy and paste multiple line text or paragraph using batch file?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `(echo | set /p= hello & echo.world) |clip`

Comment: The command you are doing is only clipping "world" since the outputs are different commands. You are clipping the output of `echo.world` but if you make the two commands one with `()` around the commands, the clip will clip both

Comment: that `set /P` trick is used to write a line *without `CRLF`*. You want that `CRLF` ("NewLine"), so don*t use `set /p`. `(echo hello&echo world)|clip`

Answer (score 3):

Like Nico wrote, if you have several lines of text, then you’ll need to wrap them in brackets `()` like this:

```
echo off | clip
(
echo This is line one
echo This is line two
echo this is line three
)| clip
```

More information about it you can find [here](https://scunster.co.uk/?p=1104).