# Overwriting Copy command

Tags: python, copy-paste

I am trying to overwrite the command Copy - Ctrl+C with the output result I have processed in my Python Script.

For eg. my script output result return `this-is-a-test`, and if I run paste (Ctrl+V), it should paste `this-is-a-test`

Is this achievable in Python context, linux environment?

Comment: Should this be working in windows/linux env?

Comment: Well, anyway - this is for linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606062/is-there-a-way-to-directly-send-a-python-output-to-clipboard and this is for windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python

Comment: linux, edited in my post.. my bad!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to directly send a python output to clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606062/is-there-a-way-to-directly-send-a-python-output-to-clipboard)

Comment: I tried the linux method given by NullUserException.. I got `File "/apps/Linux64/aw/maya2016/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
#     raise child_exception
# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory # `

Comment: Do you have `xsel` installed?

Comment: Unfortunately no I do not.. I am doing this from my company system in which I can't install anything.. And so I am asking if there is a pythonic way to do so

Comment: Are you able to install python libraries?

Comment: btw, which dist of linux you use?

Comment: Don't think so but I can try to see if I can install. I am using Red Hat 4.4.7-4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pyperclip` library](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) which is a cross platform and should work on windows/linux/mac.

```
>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
>>> pyperclip.paste()
'The text to be copied to the clipboard.'
```

If you can't install any library you can check the code ([on github](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip)) and use parts of it. It might give you the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Well, it seems that I am unable to install. I suppose to do such 'copy', I will need other libraries to do so, right?

Comment: You should try that lib, it tries multiple copy solutions based on what the OS should support.

Comment: Yea.. but since I am unable to install the lib, I am looking at other solutions such as pyqt etc